# Annotation spring mvc - no mapping found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm fairly new to Spring mvc and would like to make annotation configuration for my app. No web.xml or anything like this. I have written two jsp pages, that I would like to access, two controller classes and one application class with main method as shown below:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Example of controller:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/index","/"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView index()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

and finally my pom.xml which I edited a bit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name></name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <!-- dependency versions -->   
        <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <apache.cxf.version>2.6.1</apache.cxf.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.1.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>2.5</javax.servlet.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I try to access my jsp pages thorugh localhost:8080/index i get :

```
19:08:36.344 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
19:08:36.346 [main] INFO  p.e.u.d.s.service.Application - Started Application in 5.493 seconds (JVM running for 6.496)
19:08:42.571 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
19:08:42.571 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
19:08:42.615 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 44 ms
19:08:42.651 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Can anyone could provide any help on this issue? I suspect that I should inject a bean with DispatcherServlet but I don't really know where to go with that and how to set it up properly.

Comment: Are your `@Controller` and `@Configuration` classes in the same package?

Comment: First your pom is flawed and you have a problem with your spring version. Just use the Spring Boot provided one. Remove the `spring.version` and remove the `spring-core` dependency. Also remove your `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and the `implements WebApplicationInitializer` those aren't needed. Make sure your `Application` class is either in the same package as your controllers or in the package above that. I tend to place it in a top-level package so that the `@ComponentScan` covers everything.

Comment: Thanks, the tip with moving everything to one package fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

Add follow configuration upon webMvcConfig.java

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.your.controller"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be your Application.java and IndexController.java in two different package. Then you have to mention like this. `@ComponentScan(base = "your packge")`

For complete example :- http://www.mydevgeek.com/2017/02/14/building-a-simple-rest-service-with-spring-boot/